# How to add credentials parameter in Powershell Script?

Tags: powershell

How can we add Credentials in Powershell Script? I have written a script which is using my domain credentials by default. I want to use another credentials and want to add credentials parameter in powershell syntax, When I use credential parameter it should prompt for credentials.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using for better understanding. In general there should be an "-Credential" parameter followed by the username and password you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers have pointed out, just add a $Credential parameter to your script's PARAM block.  This answer gives a bit more detail on some of the additional pieces you can add to make things fancy.

```
Param (
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty 
)
```

### What's going on:

- `PARAM ( <# ... #> )` defines a comma separated list of possible parameters.  In this case we only have 1 parameter: `$Credential`.
- `[Parameter()]` states that this is a parameter.  We can create rules here (e.g. make the field mandatory, or only available in certain parameter sets, etc).  When there's nothing specified as in this example it's not really needed, but included for completeness.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/parameter-attribute-declaration for detail.
- `[ValidateNotNull()]` - ensure that someone doesn't assign `$null` to the parameter as that may cause unexpected behavior if not handled explicitly.
- `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]` defines the type of this parameter; i.e. it's an instance of the [PSCredential class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential?view=pscore-6.2.0).
- `[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]` - this is a [type converter](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/understanding-powershells-type-conversion-magic/); responsible for allowing PS to be helpful/intelligent in what it accepts, rather than insisting on receiving a PSCredential.  i.e. If you pass a string `-Credential 'username'` to the parameter, this is the line that will cause PowerShell to convert that string to a PSCredential, and to prompt for the related password.
- `$Credential` - This is the parameter's name.
- `= [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty` - this is where we assign a default value if no value's passed at runtime.  The empty value avoids null exception issues should you try to access the type's properties (e.g. so `$Credential.Username.Length` won't throw an exception), and is generally understood to mean "run with the current session's credentials" (though this is not guaranteed / not always applicable, depending on context / which functions/modules you're working with).

### How to call it:

Assuming your script is saved as `MyScript.ps1` and is in the current working directory, you can do any of these (and more).

- `.\MyScript.ps1` - since credential is not mandatory, will default to an empty credential; which typically means "run as current user".
- `.\MyScript.ps1 -Credential 'myDomain\myUser'` will prompt the user for a password for the given account (user can also amend the account via the same prompt)
- `.\MyScript.ps1 -Credential $credential` - passes a pre-assigned credential object (e.g. created via `$credential = Get-Credential`) to the script.

There's a great blog post going into more detail here: http://duffney.io/AddCredentialsToPowerShellFunctions

Note: This same approach applies for any PARAM block; i.e. it can be added at the start of a PS1 file so the script takes parameters, added to a function where that function takes parameters, or to a script block (e.g. script held as a variable).  See http://www.powertheshell.com/bp_function_parameters/ for more info on this.

Comment: Is the `[System.Management.Automation.Credential()]` still necessary? I've found that it still prompts for a password even without it.

Comment: After some more testing, I've found that when you add the `[PSCredential]` type annotation (either the full type name or with the accelerator), PowerShell seems to automatically add the `System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute`.

You can see this when you `(Get-Command foo).Parameters['Credential'].Attributes`

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    $Credential = $null
)

if ($Credential -is [String]) {
    $Credential = Get-Credential $Credential
}
```

If you pass a credential object to the script it will use that object:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
.\script.ps1 -Credential $cred
```

If you pass a string to the script it will prompt for a password:

```
.\script.ps1 -Credential 'username'
```

If you invoke the script without the `-Credential` parameter the parameter value will be `$null`:

```
.\script.ps1
```

If you don't want to be able to pass arguments to the parameter and only want it to indicate whether or not to prompt for credentials you could make it a switch parameter:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [switch]$Credential
)

if ($Credential.IsPresent) {
    $cred = Get-Credential
}
```

I don't think it's possible to have a parameter `-Credential` that works with and without arguments unless you put it as a switch parameter in one parameter set and as a "regular" parameter in another parameter set. That would require distinguishable parameter sets, though.

I also don't think it's possible to do this entirely in a parameter definition, at least with static parameters. Not sure about dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the parameter in your script:

```
param(
      [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
      $Credential = $(Get-Credential)
    )
```

If you pass a valid `PSCredential` object then it will proceed as normal and the script can use the credentials:

```
$cred = Get-Credential

.\MyScript.ps1 -Credential $cred
```

If you don't pass any credentials, the user will see the standard UI credential prompt.

Comment: Thanks It worked.. but it doesn't prompt for credentials until we provide username.

Comment: @Harjit, not sure what you mean, but it works as described for me.

Comment: @Harjit If you're asking how you could invoke your script/function with just the parameter without an argument (`.\script.ps1 -Credential`): I don't think that's possible, at least not if you want to be able to pass an argument too (otherwise you could make it a switch parameter).

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much !